# Controller en MVC para mismo Modelo pero distinto rol

Tags: c#, mvc

Buenos días,
Estoy estudiando y no tengo mucha idea de como hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo productos como entidad. En el modelo MVC tengo su Controller y su ProductViewModels. Bien he usado esto para el Admin, este crear modifica y elimina productos. Pero la duda que tengo ahora es:

Los clientes ven los productos para comprarlos, ¿como hago para crear in index Nuevo para estos clientes? Me refiero a estructura de carpetas, en el mismo controller...

Se que tengo que hacer un modelo Nuevo para estos, para que vean alguna cosa  menos que el admin. PEro la duda es el controlador, ya que he usado el Index para listar los productos al admin... 
¿como lo hago para que se vean los productos para el usuario?
Se ve productos-> listado con una imagen, luego pinchas y ves los detalles (usada por admin también)....

Ya tengo la carpeta product creada en la vista (view).
Un saludo

Comment: Buenas, por favor, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que utilizas Identity para el manejo de usuarios y roles también existen otras formas de mostrar contenido en una pagina en dependencia del usuario. Te explico una via simple en la que puedes utilizar el mismo Index para 2 roles.

suponiendo que en tu vista Index del controlador x renderizas el cuerpo de la tabla, puedes definir que botones se pueden o no ver para el usuario logeado de esta forma:

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellidos)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cargo)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Entidad)
            </td>
            <td>                    
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm view" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Detalles" href="@Url.Action("Detalles", new {Id = item.Id})"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i></a>

                  @if (User.IsInRole("ADMINISTRADOR"))
                      {
                         <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar" href="@Url.Action("Editar", new {Id = item.Id})"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                         <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm eliminar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar" href="@Url.Action("Eliminar", new {Id = item.Id})"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                        }

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

de esta forma estas definiendo que todos los usuarios que puedan acceder a Index verán el boton Detalles, pero solo los usuarios logeados como Administrador podran ver el boton Editar y Eliminar. Esto puedes usarlo en la vista que desees y para mostrar lo que quieras. Siempre recuerda que en el controlador ya tendrias que especificar los usuarios en la anotación [Authorize] para cada acción. Esta es una via simple de reutilizar tus vistas y para salir rapido del apuro, pero en aplicaciones grandes y complejas deberias hacer uso de Areas como añade Sergio Parrra en su respuesta, por lo que deberias echarle un vistazo. Espero te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

en ASP.NET MVC existe el concepto de `Area`. Es una característica que se usa para organizar funcionalidad relacionada entre sí como un espacio de nombres separado o una estructura de carpetas diferente. Puedes crear un área para el administrador y otra para clientes. Aquí tienes un post sobre qué son las Áreas y cómo se implementa. [Áreas en ASP.NET MVC – Una forma de organizar nuestras aplicaciones](https://diegobersano.com.ar/2015/01/05/areas-en-asp-net-mvc-una-forma-de-organizar-nuestras-aplicaciones/)

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a echar un vistazo.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la ayuda, al final lo he realizado con Areas, pero probaré con esta otra opción también, seguro que me toca usarlar cuando implemente los roles.